# Problems resizing bar button

Tags: ios, swift

I am having some difficulties creating a bar button that are leaving me pretty stumped. Im using the following code to create a right bar button:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22))
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "tune"), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(viewController.settingsBtnPressed), for:.touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

No matter what I set the width or height as the button size does not change. The VC is in a navigation controller. Does anyone have any insight or next steps I can take? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Lucas Why use a `UIButton`? You can create a `UIBarButtonItem` from an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem arises due to how bar buttons are handled in iOS 11. `UIBarButtonItem`now uses autolayout instead of frames. As a result, the following code allows you to adjust the size of the button:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.0).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on your ViewController in StoryBoard. Go to **"Editor"** -> **"Embed In"** -> Click on **"Navigation Controller"**.After that paste the code in your ViewDidLoad method where you want to see the BarButton.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "tune"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.settingsBtnPressed), for:.touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}
```

Comment: What is the differences between this and my already posted code?

Comment: You want to embed Navigation Controller. This code is on swift 4. Changes in addTarget method of a  button in Swift 4

Comment: It is already embedded in a navigation controller. Sorry I forgot to mention that above and have now edited my question

Comment: Can you please share a project?

Answer (score 0):

// The height and minimum value of this button will be affected by the rightBarButtonItem

[Button height is 100000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBimZ.png)

[Button height is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHhCD.png)

[ You can this ]

```
    // Provide a vew to button 
    let tView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 40));
    tView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 22))
    //button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "tune"), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ViewController.settingsBtnPressed), for:.touchUpInside)
    // add btton to tView
    tView.addSubview(button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: tView)
```